# Can protobuf-net be used to (de)serialize a list containing heterogeneous objects?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

Is it possible to (de)serialize a list of heterogeneous objects?

Comment: (please don't address questions directly to individuals, even me ;p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `List<object>` poses a number of challenges for a serialization format that *does not include type metadata*... but as always, there are tricks, traps, and workarounds.

If you mean *at the outermost level*, there are a few options here that revolve around using a different tag(/field-number) to indicate the message type. This is useful on an API (for example, a socket conversation) where different messages might be expected at any time. As example would be: [How can I send multiple types of objects across Protobuf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048650/how-can-i-send-multiple-types-of-objects-across-protobuf/3057111#3057111)

Inside a message is somewhat trickier; if the list of candidate types is small, then a reasonable workaround is something like presented here: [Protobuf attributes with a hierarchy of generic classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1296791/23354), i.e. treating each anticipated type as a specialization.

If the type can't be predicted, then v2 includes another workaround, but including more metadata than normal; see http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/03/objects-graphs-and-all-that-jazz.html

Comment: OK, I get the picture. My first question (more are likely to follow) is it possible to gain the ProtoInclude effect without actually touching the base type declaration. Using a model, probably? In case of List<object> I would like to use ProtoInclude on the object type, but obviously I cannot touch its declaration.

Comment: If it truly is a `List<object>` and cant change, then attributes-or-not; currently the last method described is the only viable option. I would recommend, however, using a DTO stack more amenable to the serialization. Re the includes: yes, they can be added via a RuntimeTypeModel