# How to receive packages via TCP and protobuf-net

Tags: c#, tcp, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm writing an application that uses protocol buffers C #. 
I need some example of how to send and receive data via TCP. 
Especially, how to determine which type of package has arrived.
I have classes:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Package1
{
//fields
} 
[ProtoContract]
class Package2
{
//fields 
}
```

and methods for writing to stream

```
private static void SendPackage(Stream stream, Package1 package)
{
   Serializer.Serialize<Package1>(stream, package);
}

private static void SendPackage(Stream stream, Package2 package)
{
   Serializer.Serialize<Package2>(stream, package);
}
```

Now, how to determine which type of package has arrived?

```
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    switch(packageType)
    {
       //deserialize package
    }
}
```

P.S sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Serializer.NonGeneric method which you can use to identify the object. See this question and answer [How can I send multiple types of objects across Protobuf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048650/how-can-i-send-multiple-types-of-objects-across-protobuf)